# How to solve "op_cant_change"?

Tags: authorization

I set authorization immutable flag to be true. 
Then I got "op_cant_change". 
How can I set it to be false again?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. That's the purpose of `AUTHORIZATION IMMUTABLE`: to allow asset holders to have trust that the asset will not be revoked, or the account deleted in the future. From [the docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html):

> **Ensuring asset holders they won’t be revoked:** the above functionalities are great for asset issuers who wish to control who can and cannot hold/transact their asset. However, what if I am an asset holder and I am worried that an issuer may freeze the assets I hold? To instill trust in potential asset holders, the issuing account can enable the following flag:
>
> `AUTHORIZATION IMMUTABLE`: with this setting, none of the authorization flags can be set and the account can never be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much.